# Can not properly type ProtectedRoute React custom component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple `ProtectedRoute`  component which works fine:

```
interface Props {
    children: ReactNode;
}

export const ProtectedRoute = (props: Props) => {
    const isLogged = useSelector(getLoginStatus, shallowEqual);

    if (!isLogged) {
        return <NotLogged /> as any;
    }

    return props.children;
};
```

but has `any` applied as you see. And this `any` makes it works, otherwise compilation error. I tried to replace that `any` many ways:

```
JSX.Element

JSX.Element | null
```

`()=>JSX.Element` (technically  is a simple component of  ()=>JSX.Element type;

```
ReactNode
```

and few more, but it throws error

```
TS2786: 'ProtectedRoute' cannot be used as a JSX component.
```

Its return type 'string | number | boolean | Iterable | Element | null | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.

Only `any` does the job here. What are correct types here?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are just missing an `[]` after `ReactNode`?

It seems that your `ProtectedRoute` seems to be a list of ReactNodes, and `children` is also a list of ReactNodes.

So I think this could work:

```js
interface Props {
    children: ReactNode[];
}

export const ProtectedRoute = (props: Props): ReactNode[] => {
    const isLogged = useSelector(getLoginStatus, shallowEqual);

    if (!isLogged) {
        return [<NotLogged />];
    }

    return props.children;
};
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot that React doesn't allow to return arrays of ReactNodes as components. Try this instead:

```js
export const ProtectedRoute = (props: Props): ReactNode => {
    const isLogged = useSelector(getLoginStatus, shallowEqual);

    if (!isLogged) {
        return <NotLogged />;
    }

    return <>{props.children}</>;
};
```

Comment: after your changes it throws TS error: 'ProtectedRoute' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'ReactNode[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I updated my answer. Does it work with the new code?